# What does it mean when the rate of convergence is not two when using the trapezoidal rule?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

For $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on the interval $[0,1]$ and $N = 16,32,64,128$, the ratio of my errors is not $4$, so the rate of convergence is not 2. Instead I get ~$2.8$ which means the rate of convergence is ~1.485. What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ doesn't have a bounded second derivative (or a bounded first derivative for that matter), so the errors close to $x=0$ decay rather slowly.